# Add equations to text

Tags: math-mode

I've got a really simple question. I'd like to write a mathematical proof in LaTeX, so my document will contain both text and formulae embedded in it. For example, I want to add this to it:

[image]

How can I write this efficiently, without putting the entire text into an `\mbox{}` element?

Comment: @murgatroid99: You're right, I didn't know of this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only wrap the equations in `$...$`, you can enter and leave math mode all throughout the document.

[This page](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/MathMode.html) shows examples with formulas both inline in a paragraph and on their own lines.

Answer (score 2):

If most of the content is math mode, the use `\text{}` to imbed text within equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Let } D \subseteq \mathbf{R}, D \ne 0
\]

or in inline mode: $\text{Let } D \subseteq \mathbf{R}, D \ne 0$
\end{document}
```